# How to (lazy) data load the same big dataset from multiple python modules

Tags: python, design-patterns, software-design

I have multiple (python) modules where I use the same input data and also the variables have the same names.

I created a module `data_loading.py` where the variables are instantiated. I then import the variables I need in the `data_analysis_xx` modules.

For example,

```
" Module data_analysis_1 "
from data_loading import var_1, var_2,…, var_k 

" Module data_analysis_2 "
from data_loading import var_1, var_3
```

In this way I avoid to copy-and-paste the same 200 lines of code in every module to load the same or partially the same  set of data

#### First question:

#### is using a single source module for data loading the right approach? Is there a standard way or anyway a better way for importing the same variables in multiple modules?

#### Problem:

However when I import data_loading, all the variables in it are loaded/processed even if I actually import only one or few variables. 
This can be time consuming, especially because in data_loading I also do some basic data manipulation (check, split, cut, sort, etc.)

#### Second question:

#### how to make the data_loading module work such that only the variables that really need to be loaded/processed are actually processed?

## Possible solutions

1. split data_loading in multiple sub-modules --> slightly reduces the problem but increases the number of files to load from: complexity, caos, error prone. Not good
2. create a class that deals with the data loading and loads only the variable via the class?
   How to do this practically? 
   How do I import the variables then? 
   "from data_loading import Loader.var_1 as var_1 …, Loader.var_k as var_k" ?
3. implement lazy loading --> 
   Many of my variables are classes that deal with the actual data loading (retrieving the data from a file). Hence, lazy loading would help in reducing the total cost in terms of time.

   References:

   - [How to lazy load a data structure (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558763/how-to-lazy-load-a-data-structure-python)
   - cached functions via descriptor (descriptor: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol)
   - https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/10b4b8b6918a83712170fdaabd3ec61cf07f23ff/werkzeug/utils.py
   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849299/7074426

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

One way to deal with all your issues is to create a factory that will create singleton in demand.

- [factory](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html)
- [singleton](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html)

With this two design pattern you can instantiate class and create variable only when needed (factory) and you can reuse them without compute them again in several module (singleton)

### Edit 1

here is a pratical application with pseudocode exemple.

In my script I need variable in order to cumpute something. These variables are : pi with a define number of floating point, fibonacci of several number and prime number.

I create a script with functions to compute each variables I need, but each function have a cache that will capture the computed value.

```py
#compute_variables.py

def pi(n):
    pass

def fibonaci(n):
    pass

def prime_number(n):
    pass
```

All of these function are calculation intensive and should be only vompute once per variables .

Now I need class that will return the desired vaibales allready compute in a singleton (only one object is return everytime)

```py
#variables.py

class Calculus1:

    def __new__(cls):
        #singleton logic

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def var1(self):
        return pi(self.a)

    def var2(self):
        return fibonaci(self.b)

    def var3(self):
        return prime_number(self.c)   

class Calculus2:

    def __new__(cls):
        #singleton logic

    def __init__(self, a, b, e):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.e = e

    def var1(self):
         return pi(self.a)

    def var2(self):
        return fibonaci(self.b)

    def var3(self):
        return prime_number(self.e)
```

I have the bear bone, know I need a factory that return singleton of variables class .

```py
# factory_meth.py

def  factory(var_class_name):
    # Factory logic here 
    myVars = CalculusX(x, y, z)
    return myVars
```

And finaly I used all this implementation in my application .

```py
from  factory_meth import factory

def fancy_something_1(f, g):
    vars = factory("Calculus2")
    return      (f * vars.vars1 / (vars.vars2 + vars.vars3))**g

def fancy_something_2(z ,h):
    vars = factory("Calculus2")
    return  z + vars.vars1 vars.vars2 + vars.vars3 + h
```

With this logic, all variables will be call and compute only when needed (factory), where even if a variables is recall, there will be no computation as its the same object return (singleton).

### Note

The above architecture is one way to achieve lazy load and on demand call, but the design may be adjust to feat your need.

Comment: what do you mean in practice? In Solution 2 I suggest to use a class. Can this be the factory you mention?

Comment: Thank you. The indentation in Calculus2 is screwed, right? I don't think that's on purpose

Answer (score 1):

You could simply move the actions associated with each dataset inside of a function, and then import that function. This could be a single function that takes a parameter to select the dataset, or multiple functions, perhaps one function per dataset.

The one function per dataset case might look like:

```py
def load_val_1():
    val_1 = ...  # Create and preprocess val_1 here
    ...
    return val_1
```

Then you would `from data_loading import load_val_1` and create val_1 by calling the function you imported. The functions could even be static methods or class methods of a class, in which case you would only need to import that class.